Compute the cohomology ring of $G=\langle u,v\mid uvuv=vuvu\rangle$.
I am trying to compute the integral cohomology ring of the following group:
$$G=\langle u,v\mid uvuv=vuvu\rangle$$
First, I managed to compute the cohomology groups:
$$H^0(G,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}e_0,H^1(G,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}e_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_2,H^2(G,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}e_3$$
and $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z})=0~\forall~i\geq 3$. Hence, $H^\ast(G,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}e_0\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_3$. To understand the ring structure we need to compute the cup product of the generators, which are:
$$e_i\smile e_i=0~\forall~i=0,1,2,3$$
$$e_0\smile e_i=e_i~\forall~i=0,1,2,3$$
$$e_1\smile e_2=2e_3$$
and $e_i\smile e_j=0$ for every other $i,j$. I would like to know whether $H^\ast(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to a well known ring, such as a polynomial ring or some exterior algebra.

I'm interested; how did you comute these $H^k$?

Just a note: letting $x=uv$ gives an equivalent presentation $\langle x,u\mid [x^2,u]\rangle$. The normal closure $N=\langle x^2,u\rangle^G$ is such that $[G:N]=2$ and $N\cong\mathbb{Z}\times F_2$, with the $\mathbb{Z}$ factor coming from the central $x^2$ and the free $F_2$ factor generated by $u$ and $u^x$.

@FShrike $G$ is an Artin group, and there is a canonical free resolution to  compute the (co)homology of those groups.

@SteveD Is this related with my problem? Because I dont see the relation of your claim with my problem.

I was just finding a finite-index right-angled Artin group inside yours. This also follows from the fact your group is just $F_2\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$, with the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ acting by swapping the generators of $F_2$.

Do you mean $e_0\frown e_0=e_0$? As it stands, this is not a unital ring.

Also, the cohomology ring is with respect to the cup product, written $\smile$, not the cap product, written $\frown$.

@JoshuaTilley You're right! Those where misprints.

If I understand you correctly, the ring you are looking at is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module with basis $e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3$ where $e_0$ is the identity, $e_3=\frac{1}{2}e_1\smile e_2$, $e_1^2=e_2^2=0$, and the ring is graded commutative with $e_1$ and $e_2$ in degree $1$. Therefore, $e_0,e_3$ are even degree, and hence central, and
$$e_1\smile e_2=-e_2\smile e_1.$$
This ring is almost the exterior algebra $\bigwedge \mathbb{Z}^2$ with $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by $e_1,e_2$. Specifically, the subring generated by $e_1,e_2$ is the copy of $\bigwedge \mathbb{Z}^2$ spanned by $e_0,e_1,e_2,2e_3$ - an index 2 subgroup of the entire cohomology ring. Since $e_3=\frac{1}{2}e_1\smile e_2$, the desired ring $R$ is actually stricly between $\bigwedge \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\bigwedge \mathbb{Q}^2$.
I doubt it has a name because there are a lot of rings $R$ with $\bigwedge \mathbb{Z}^2\subset R\subset \bigwedge \mathbb{Q}^2$.
